# Race Conditions at Fault for Filtered Data Not Being Consistent in Angular App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have a situation where I am giving the user an option of filtering data being returned from the API in our Angular front-end, MongoDB/Node back-end app. The filters are acting as expected, in the sense that the data filters appropriately when the user selects or enters various UI-based filters (example, for ZIP code, language, etc).

Furthermore, the filter selections are being saved in the URL, so that a user can return to a component, or even keep track of a URL, and by loading that URL, all of the previous filter selections will be applied. That's also working as expected -- to a point.

I also have a pageChange() function, that fires whenever a user moves to another iteration of the pagination. And the pageChange() function looks at the URL to make sure the filters continue to be applied as the user paginates through results. The pageChange() function works perfectly as is.

The problem I'm running into, and that I'm trying to reason about, is that if the user navigates away from, and then returns to a page/component, then sometimes (maybe one time out of twenty), the data will filter, and then un-filter -- right there on the screen, when they return to the page and the component re-mounts. So what the user ends up with is data that's not filtered according to the filters showing in the URL and that should still be coming through via the filter inputs. So it seems like, again, one time out of twenty or so, what I'm running into is the consequence of race conditions.

To add further clarity, the filter selections are being passed through to the component from a secondary filter-component. I'm doing this using Angular's `Output()` and `EventEmitter()`.

This is what the code in my component looks like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FiltersService } from '../../../../data/filters.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { API } from './../../../../data/api.service';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { TabPage } from '../../../../ui/tab-navigation/tab-page';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TableDisplayComponent } from './../../table-display/table-display.component';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './clients.html'
})
export class ClientsComponent extends TabPage
{
    private section: string;
    records = {};
    data;
    errorMsg: string = 'Server Error';
    page: number = 0;
    pagesize = 12;
    currentStage: string = 'clients';

  ...

    constructor(private FiltersService: filtersService,
                private router: Router,
                private route: ActivatedRoute)
    {
        super();

        this._title = 'Clients';
        this.contentId = 'clients-page';
    }

    body: any = { $or: [ { "group-a" : "clients" },
                         { "group-b" : "clients" },
                                                  ] };

    private processType(body, propName: string, value: any)
    {
        this.filtersService.processType(body, propName, value);
    }

    private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string, page)
    {
        this.filtersService.onFilterReceived(this.body, value, type);

        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: any) => {
                page = params['page'];
            }
        );

        let fn = resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            let data = resRecordsData.data;
            console.log(data);
        };

        this.filtersService.getByFilter(page - 1, this.pagesize, this.body, fn);
    }

    public pageChange(page, value, type, body)
    {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: any) => {
                this.page = params['page'];
                this.pn_lang_e = params['pn_lang_e'];
                this.pn_lang_s = params['pn_lang_s'];
                this.pn_locations_e = params['pn_locations_e'];
                this.pn_locations_s = params['pn_locations_s'];
                this.pn_branches_e = params['branches_e'];
                this.pn_branches_s = params['branches_v'];
            }
        );

        this.router.navigate(
            ['/clients', {
                page: page,
                pn_lang_e: this.pn_lang_e,
                pn_lang_s: this.pn_lang_s,
                pn_locations_e: this.pn_locations_e,
                pn_locations_s: this.pn_locations_s,
                branches_e: this.pn_branches_e,
                branches_s: this.pn_branches_s
            }]);

        let fn = resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            let data = resRecordsData.data;
        };

        this.filtersService.getByFilter(page - 1, this.pagesize, this.body, fn);
    }

}
```

The filters are being passed via the body of a POST request. The code in the FiltersService (that is being used in the component above) that handle that look like this:

```
public getByFilter(page, pagesize, body, fn?: any)
{
    return this.apiService.post({req: this.strReq, reqArgs: {page: page, pagesize: pagesize}, reqBody: body, callback: fn});
}

public processType(body, propName: string, value: any)
{
    if (body[propName] && !value || body[propName] && value.length < 1) {
        delete body[propName];
    } else if (value) {
        body[propName] = { $in: value };
    }
}

public onFilterReceived(body, value: any, type: string)
{
    if (type === 'lan')
    {
        this.processType(body, 'languages.primary', value);
    } if (type === 'zip')
    {
        this.processType(body, 'addresses.postalCode', value);
    } if (type === 'branch')
    {
        this.processType(body, 'branch', value);
    }
}
```

Lastly, it's in the view for the component that I'm taking in the filters:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <table-display [records]="records"
        [currentStage]="currentStage"
        (sendLocation)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'location')"
        (sendChange)="pageChange($event)"
        (sendZipcode)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'zip')"
        (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'lan')"
        (sendBranch)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'branch')">
    </table-display>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is make sure I get consistent results, 100% of the time. Also, even when the data does resolve properly, sometimes it visually switches between filtered and unfiltered data, before resolving to the filtered data - which also is visually distracting and clearly not ideal.

What is the issue in the above code that makes the filters not apply that one time out of twenty when the component re-loads? Are race conditions at fault? Or is something else the problem - perhaps order of operations? And what can I do to address this?

EDIT: It occurs to me that a way I could perhaps resolve this is to force the component to look at the URL when the component first loads - to pick up the filter selections if they exist. That's what happens when the pageChange() function fires, and that works perfectly. So maybe I need to do something similar every time the component loads? What would that look like?